# Why does the object first appear after calling the Api, but then it is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem that I do not understand and I have not found an answer to it.

```
fetch(i.login.url, {
      method: i.login.methodType,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        var prom;
        if (!response.ok) {
           prom = response.json() as Promise<ResultModel<boolean>>;
           prom.then((result) => {
           
           console.log("1: ",result);          // 1. Here is the object
           console.log("2: ",result.Message);  // 2. Here is undefined

          });
```

1. Here is the object

```
{isSuccess: false, message: "Uživatel nepřihlášen. Email je null, nebo nevyplněný. (Parameter 'Email')", data: false}
> data: false
  isSuccess: false
  message: "Uživatel nepřihlášen. Email je null, nebo nevyplněný. (Parameter 'Email')"
```

This is the console output, and it is correct.

2. Here is undefined

```
undefined
```

Here the value is undefined in the console and I don't understand why.

I tried this:

```
var p = new ResultModel<boolean>(result);
console.log(p);

ResultModel {IsSuccess: false, Message: '', Data: undefined}
>Data: undefined
 IsSuccess: false
 Message: ""
 [[Prototype]]: Object
```

but the result is again bad.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your ResultModel has Captial M while the real object has "
*message* key while you are logging with
*Message.* key.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I changed to lower case.

Answer (score -1):

should be

```
console.log("2: ",result.message);
```

message uncapitalized

instead of

```
console.log("2: ",result.Message);
```

you can see that your keys are uncapitalized when you log the object, however your ResultModel show  capitalized keys. So your ResultModel type is not correct

you can change the ResultModel in TypeScript the following way

```
type NewResultModel = {
  [Prop in keyof ResultModel as Uncapitalize<Prop & string>]: ResultModel[Prop]
}
```

Then replace your ResultModel with the  NewResultModel

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I changed to lower case.